# Count null values in a single column using hiveql

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I would like to count the number of null values in a single column.

With:

```
select count(1)
from usedcars3
where model is NULL
```

I managed to get count of the null values in a single column in SQL however when I ran:

```
select count(1) 
from usedcars3 
where model is null;
```

in hive,

it gave me back 0 as the result.

I've searched around and haven't found anything as to why.

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The query should run fine in Hive.  You just don't have `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from usedcars3 where model is null;
```